# How does 見ての work here?

Tags: grammar, nuances, て-form

I found this sentence and I don't know how the grammar works here:

俺たちを見ての反応。

Why is the verb in its て form? and is it different from saying "俺たちを見た反応"?

Comment: 見ての反応 is more explicit (or emphatic) about the cause-result relationship. For example, 俺たちを見ての反応だった may be translated emphatically as "His reaction was definitely because he saw us."